# making columns out of items of columns of the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, database, statistics

I think my problem lies in not correctly converting and then trying to loop through them,
I want to do a statistics analysis on each day activities, by making a negative list, then calculate if the day had any negativities in it! there are NAT problems and others ...

the df top 10

```
    full_date   weekday mood    activities
0   2023-07-31  Monday  meh 自炊 | nothing at all | Game
1   2023-07-30  Sunday  meh nothing at all | Game
2   2023-07-29  Saturday    meh pizza | nothing at all | Game | outside food | 
3   2023-07-28  Friday  meh nothing at all | Game | outside food
4   2023-07-27  Thursday    meh nothing at all | Game | argument
5   2023-07-26  Wednesday   meh nothing at all | Game
6   2023-07-25  Tuesday meh 自炊 | nothing at all | Game | outside food
7   2023-07-24  Monday  meh Game
8   2023-07-23  Sunday  meh 自炊 | with a friend | family like gathering | Game | argument
9   2023-07-22  Saturday    meh self teaching | nothing at all | Game
```

first I clean and split the column so I can loop thought them ;

```
df["activities"]=df["activities"].astype("string")
df["activities"]=df["activities"].str.split("|")
```

```
full_date   weekday mood    activities
0   2023-07-31  Monday  meh [自炊 , nothing at all , Game]
1   2023-07-30  Sunday  meh [nothing at all , Game]
2   2023-07-29  Saturday    meh [pizza , nothing at all , Game , outside food , argument]
3   2023-07-28  Friday  meh [nothing at all , Game , outside food ]
4   2023-07-27  Thursday    meh [nothing at all , Game , argument]
5   2023-07-26  Wednesday   meh [nothing at all , Game]
6   2023-07-25  Tuesday meh [自炊 , nothing at all , Game , outside food ]
7   2023-07-24  Monday  meh [Game]
8   2023-07-23  Sunday  meh [自炊 , with a friend , family like gathering , Game , argument]
9   2023-07-22  Saturday    meh [self teaching , nothing at all , Game]
```

Im tring to get rid of the white spaces, by evrything, strip; is not working ! , and replacing (" ","") give something like this : "nothing at all"  ---> "nothingatall"

then I want to loop thorogh the activiteis column and make a new column that shows how many activites had been done in that day;

```
for i in df['activities']:
    df["actions"]= len(i)
```

its stopping at the first loop, making an uncomplete database and gives error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[211], line 2
      1 for i in df['activities']:
----> 2     df["actions"]= len(i)

TypeError: object of type 'NAType' has no len()
```

another issue that I want to make a column which check the negative deeds based on the list ;

```
negative=["nothing at all", "Game","argument"," outside food"]
df["negative_acts"]=0
for i in df['activities']:
    if i is (negative):
        df["negative_acts"] +=1
    else :
        df["negative_acts"]=df["negative_acts"]
```

but nothing ...

sorry for long issues

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are not doing what you expect (I expect that the following will solve part of the problems but not the TypeError you got). For example, the result of your loop:

```
for i in df['activities']:
    df["actions"]= len(i)
```

will assign to all elements of the column "actions" the length of the list of the last element df['activities'], which is not what you want.

Instead, you can use the functions [pandas assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) or [pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to assign all elements of the columns with the desired value. For example, with `pd.apply()`, the first loop will be rewritten as:

```
df['actions'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(row['activities']), axis=1)
```

The same problem arises with your last loop. To solve this, I would create a function `count_deeds()` and use again the apply() function:

```
negative=["nothing at all", "Game","argument"," outside food"]
def count_deeds(activities):
     return sum(el in negative for el in activities)

df["negative_acts"] = df.apply(lambda row: count_deeds(row["activities"]), axis=1)
```